# What's the best way to markup an empty element?

Tags: javascript, semantic-web, semantic-markup, xhtml

Let's say an empty div or span that will be used by JavaScript to add something, as

```
<div id='id'></div>
```

Semantically it's wrong, because it can't be empty (I forgot in the moment the reason). We use then

```
<div id='id'>&nbsp;</div>
```

until, if, JavaScript do its magic.

But I also don't like it, because there's not really a space there. I'd do

```
<div id='id' />
```

but [self closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-practice/348818#348818) explains its issues.

Is there any other solution I can't think of? or is & nbsp; really the best?

Note that this is about HTML document, not how it's rendered by a browser. For browser we just set it to not be rendered and then show it with JS.

Edit: Yes, the div is semantcally wrong. It's meant to have some content in it, otherwise it's useless semantically. [Eric Meyer CSS Diagnostic](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/diagnostics/demo-not.html) says it. If I'm understanding it wrong, instead of negging me, teach me...

Comment: The div is not empty, it has an ID. You might want to do something with it later or just link to it. So what?

Comment: Yes it is empty. If I use :empty CSS flag in it and set any style, that style will be applied to it.

Comment: For HTML to be "semantically wrong", it must convey a meaning that you don't intend to convey. Absence of any content is semantically null, so if `<div></div>` is "semantically wrong" it must be conveying some meaning. What is the meaning that you think it is conveying? Also, see what the HTML5 spec has to say about [palpable content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#palpable-content)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/561826/652722).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is writing self closing tags for elements not traditionally empty bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-practice)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/561826/652722 answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the schema allows it

```
<span /> is equivalent to <span></span>
only in XML documents (read xhtml in your case)
```

second:

```
<span /> is as empty as <span></span> is
```

because in both cases childNodes length is 0

you need `&nbsp;` because of what?

Comment: It's not about schema validity or document wellformedness, it's about Semantic. & nbsp; is needed to have some content in it and solve Semantic problem.

Comment: if it is about semantic, they are equivalent, both are empty

Comment: also an empty tag doesn't mean that is useless... document's "Semantic" is defined by schema or dtd, then what are you asking here?

Comment: Many years ago I learned to use nbsp on empty elements, because of Semantics. I wanted to know if there's a better solution, because nbsp isn't good at all for me, since it still has "nothing" in it and I didn't want a space there. Why Eric Meyer and other Semantic experts complain of empty elements then?

Answer (score 5):

Semantically wrong? Why? A DIV does not imply anything. An empty `H1` would be semantically wrong, but not a DIV.

Comment: So why did Eric Meyer included it, together with span, li, p and td into his CSS Diagnostic?

Comment: Why not write to him, forward the link to this question and see what he says. It may be interesting. A DIV isn't really semantic like <p> or <li>. It's merely a container. A valid reason would be +1 for you.